# GWT ImageLoadingCell Refresh

Tags: gwt

I'm using the ImageLoadingCell class to display images in a table. It shows the spinning icon, and then the image as they are loaded. This is fine. However, when the table is refreshed, it again shows the spinning icon, until it gets the images. I'd like this to only happen the first time. Is there a way to turn off refreshing this particular column, or to make the cell smart enough not to refresh itself?

[ImageLoadingCell.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/cell/client/ImageLoadingCell.java?r=10797/ImageLoadingCell.java) - See onBrowserEvent() and render().

```
ImageLoadingCell myImgCell = new ImageLoadingCell() {
  public Set<String> getConsumedEvents() {
  }
};

Column<MeasuredFilter, String> thumbColumn = new Column<MeasuredFilter, String>(myImgCell) {
  @Override
  public String getValue(MeasuredFilter object) {
      return object.getThumbnail();
  }
```

Comment: It would be better if you could share relevant code snippets.

Comment: Show your code for this column. How do you get the images (ImageResource or URL)?

Comment: just added some code, but really, just using ImageLoadingCell "as normal".

Comment: onBrowserEvent seems to do the "real" render, and render just sets up the browser image fetch. I need it to somehow not re-render in the onBrowserEvent() method (I think).

Comment: Andrei - The getValue() method above returns a url as a string